# What weapon has the highest Dexterity scaling in Dark Souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have been messing around a bit and wondered what weapon had the highest dexterity  scaling on my dexterity /vitality build. If you do  know what weapon has the highest scaling, could you please leave where to find it in your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that dex scaling is [pretty wonky](http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/20qjf2/guide_weapon_scaling/). There's not much benefit between an A and S rank. Keep that in mind.

Also note that poison and bleeding scales with DEX.

The weapons with best DEX scaling ( A/S ) are:

[Ricard's Rapier](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ricard%27s+Rapier#.U3G6Nfl_t8E) (starts with A scaling, gets S once upgraded to +5) - Huntsman's Copse. Bottom of the pit after first bonfire.
Rare drop from Spiders in Brightstone Cove Tseldora.

[Curved Dragon Greatsword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Curved+Dragon+Greatsword#.U3G6ufl_t8E) (S)- Trade Ancient Dragon Soul with Ornifex

[Hunter's Blackbow](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Hunter%27s+Blackbow#.U3G7MPl_t8E) (S) - Found in the chest down a ladder at the second bonfire before the Dual Dragonrider boss at Drangleic Castle.

[Mirrah Greatsword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Mirrah+Greatsword#.U3G8gPl_t8E) (A) - Buy from Merchant Hag Melentia in Cardinal Tower or Majula after killing Lucatiel. Given to you in Aldia's Keep at the first bonfire by Lucatiel after following her storyline.

[Warped Sword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Warped+Sword#.U3G85fl_t8E) (A) - Trade Flexile Sentry Soul with Straid of Olaphis

[Espada Ropera](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Espada+Ropera#.U3G9LPl_t8E) (A) - talk to Chancellor Wellager in Drangleic Castle after defeating the Giant Lord to receive the Espada Ropera and the Royal Dirk.

[Caestus](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Caestus#.U3G9mPl_t8E) (A) - Purchasable from Merchant Hag Melentia

[Parrying Dagger](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Parrying+Dagger#.U3G-2Pl_t8E) (A) - Located in a chest behind a boarded up wall closest to Cell bonfire in Lost Bastille head left from the bonfire and head up the stairs and down the rampart. Go down the ladder to your left and go through the door way and head right. There will be a boarded up door. Break the boards and head through and to you left. You will see a door. Use the Antiquated Key to open it and head straight and through the doorway, climb up the ladder to your left and drop down onto the raised platform. There is a passage way that leads to 3 chests. It resides in one of them.

[Spider Fang](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Spider+Fang#.U3G_Vfl_t8E) (A) - Trade Soul of the Duke's Dear Freja to Weaponsmith Ornifex

[Uchigatana](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Uchigatana#.U3G_nvl_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +5) - Purchase from Steady Hand McDuff

[Washing Pole](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Washing+Pole#.U3G_n_l_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +10) - Dragon Shrine (Chest) (Mimic)

[Chaos Blade](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Chaos+Blade#.U3G_ovl_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +5) - Trade the Old Witch Soul with Ornifex

[Blacksteel Katana](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Blacksteel+Katana#.U3G_pPl_t8E) (stats with A, gets S on +1) - Dropped by Alonne Knights at the Iron Keep

[Manslayer](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Manslayer#.U3HAnPl_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +5) - From the rise of the dead bonfire in the Shrine of Amana go up the stairs enter the door. Make sure you are hollow and you rescued all sirens or the door will not open. From there continue along the path and through the shrine room and down the next set of stairs. Now go outside and take a left and walk along the ledge. The katana will be inside a chest to your left near the wall.

[Darkdrift](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Darkdrift#.U3HAofl_t8E) (starts with C, gets A on +10) - Talk to Grave Warden Agdayne in the Undead Crypt after obtaining the King's Ring.

[Murakumo](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Murakumo#.U3HBdfl_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +2) - Bought from Ornifex

[Arced Sword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Arced+Sword#.U3HBS_l_t8E) (starts with B, gets A on +2) - Trade Flexile Sentry Soul to Straid of Olaphis

[Spider's Silk](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Spider%27s+Silk#.U3HB8fl_t8E) (S) - Trade weapons Ornifex the Soul of the Duke's Dear Freja.

[Syan's Halberd](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Syan%27s+Halberd#.U3HCRvl_t8E) (A) - Dropped by the Knights wearing Syan's Armor(gold) and wielding halberds in Drangleic Castle

Comment: I knew that a and s are not too diffrent, but the fact that it scales around 60% when compared to strength (according to your reddit link) makes me wonder why the creaters made it this way, even more when you add the two handed  option strength weapons provide.

Comment: Because they are fast.

Comment: While I admit they are faster, when it come to damage per second I usually do better in strengeh. This is because I could use a much more powerful weapon two handed instead of two weaker ones.

Comment: What I think they wanted to accomplish is that you infuse the DEX weapons with poison/bleed, to make it more "rogue". Many DEX weapons already have poison or bleed, so you trade raw damage with damage-over-time. Some weapons are especially suited for this play-style, like Ricard's Rapir: heavy attack is a flurry of thrusts, combined with poison and you have a pretty nasty weapon.

Comment: That would make sence, I guess I should make it worth mentioning that crossbows can also benefit with this.(what crossbow would do good damage with poison?)

Comment: By far, the [Avelyn](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Avelyn#.U3MH3_l_t8E) - 3 shots in rapid succession.

Comment: I thought so, but the poison wouldn't stack.

Comment: Well, poison works like this - you hit someone and it fills up a bar. Once this bar is full, he'll get poison damage. Poison damage is set to 15 HP every half-second. The higher the poison stat, the faster this bar fills.

Comment: Oh well, nothing much more to say.